# Mozilla flexbox not working with bootstrap row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, mozilla

I am using a bootstrap 3 container, inside there is a col-sm-4 and col-sm-offset-4 for centering the form inside. 
I'd like to vertically center the form with flexbox, it's working in Chrome & Safari, but with mozilla, it's not working.

```
#login {
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
```

}

my Container above

My html code:

```
<div class="container" id="login">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 centered">
            <div class="well">
                <form action="login.php" autocomplete="off" id="Login_Form" method="post" name="Login_Form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span> <input class="form-control" name="Username" placeholder="Nutzername">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-shield fa-fw"></i></span> <input class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="Passwort" type="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary full-width-button" name="Submit" value="Login">Anmelden</button>
                    </div>
                    <table class="errormessage_table">
                        <?php if(isset($msg)){?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="errormessage"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
                        </tr><?php } ?>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

like..the container is so small, in safari the container is a lot bigger and not cut off

[Safari & Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XrFA.png)
[Mozilla Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXK5V.png)

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: please share your HTML code

Comment: I added the html code. Thanks for replying that fast :)

Comment: just add the col-xs-12 in row because the parent div display is flex it changes the behavior .

Comment: I've tried this, it works but i want the container to be small, that's why I'm using col-sm-4, if i write col-xs-12, the form will be the whole page... I want it exactly like on the Safari & Chrome Screenshot, if possible.

Comment: i have created code but couldn't   replicate issue- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zBjkWw

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm using Bootstrap 3, if you add the Bootstrap .css and .js file in your html code, it will look like on my screenshot. In safari, it's working perfectly, but in firefox not. Can you please try to add the Bootstrap CDN in your example in HTML code? Thanks :) link to bootstrap cdn: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your expected result remove display:flex

```
#login {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zBjkWw

Comment: That is working so far in all browsers, at least it is not cut off any more. And how can i center the whole  form now vertically? safari & chrome is already centered, firefox looks fine but sticks to top. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks man! This worked for me, really appreciate your help :)